# jquery FullCalendar returns http 403 error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I have integrated jquery FullCalender2.2 in my php website. It is working fine with localhost but when I upload it online in my url "http://iamfortesting.com" it returns 403 response. Please help as I am unable to get the issue. Console Log is given below-

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)  http://iamfortesting.com/......../fullcalendar.css

same is for fullcalendar.js also.

Comment: check the permissions..make it 755

Comment: do you have saved css file in css folder at root ?

Comment: yes it was a permission issue. thanks @user3571366.

Comment: no problem Anonymous :) but no points to me x(

Answer (score 0):

better you use [cdn](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/fullcalendar)

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.2/fullcalendar.min.css

//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.2/fullcalendar.min.js
```